# Why does $x^{15}+x^{14}+1$ detect all errors at most 32768 bits apart?

Tags: computer-networks, polynomials, crc

Reference Question from Forouzon Book Computer Network.
Find the status of the following generator related to two isolated, single-bit errors.
$$x^{15} + x^{14} + 1$$
**Answer** given :
This polynomial cannot divide any error of type $x^t + 1$ if t is less than 32,768. This means
that a codeword with two isolated errors that are next to each other or up to 32,768 bits
apart can be detected by this generator.
Can some one please help me why is this true...? Or even how should I have an in general approach to analyze such questions...?
(Sorry if this is very silly, but I am unable to get a grasp of how the reason works...!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your polynomial is [primitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_polynomial_(field_theory)), which means that the order of $x$ modulo your polynomial is exactly $2^{15}-1$. In particular, $x^a \not\equiv 1$ modulo your polynomial for all $1 \leq a \leq 2^{15}-2$, which means that your polynomial doesn't divide $x^a-1$ for this range of $a$.

(This also means that your polynomial should divide $x^{2^{15}-1}-1$, in contrast to what the question claims.)

Comment: Can you please explain it a bit more briefly I am trying to understand it but still stuck at how come a Database Management Course book taking me to primitive ..and plz also explain a bit more about how and why are these primitive polynomials coming to picture...(sorry if you find it silly)

Comment: The internet has an endless amount of material on primitive polynomials.

Comment: Okay so tell me one thing ..if I have $x^5+x^4+1$ then would this be also equivalent to $x^{2^5-1}-1$..?

Comment: I could look it up in a list of primitive polynomials, but so could you.

Comment: ok..now I got it thanks for help!!